# How to verify presence of a text in a row. (Assert vs Verify)

Tags: java, selenium

My application creates a new row in the table whenever a new case is added in the application. The row has few columns and content of column can be similar to that of other columns. I need to find if "*text*" is present in the row. Below is my code:

```
@Test (priority = 2)
public void SaveStatus()
{
    WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.partialLinkText("Case Listing")); //To find 'Case Listing' button on dashboard 
    Actions action = new Actions (driver);
    action.moveToElement(element); //Move mouse and hover to 'Case Listing' button 
    action.click().build().perform(); //Click on 'Case Listing' button
    List<WebElement> newcase = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//*[@id='caseList']/tbody/tr[1]"));//find the new case saved in the caselist
    String CaseStatus = ((WebElement) newcase).getText();
    if (CaseStatus.contains("Draft")){
    Assert.assertTrue(isTextPresent("Draft"));
    }
    System.out.println("Test Case 3 --> Case Status is draft");
```

I need to verify presence of the text "Draft" in that row. This text will always appear in 4 column. Other rows can also have similar text hence I don't want to use `getPageSource().contains`. This is the error I'm getting:

`java.util.ArrayList cannot be cast to org.openqa.selenium.WebElement`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Issue occuring at below line, you are using getText() for webelements. But it will be applicable only for type webelement.

```
String CaseStatus = ((WebElement) newcase).getText();
```

You need to use for loop to loop through all the webelements in the list and verify the text.

example:Assuming id of the table is caseList

```
    WebElement table_element = driver.findElement(By.id("caseList"));
    List<WebElement> tr_collection=table_element.findElements(By.xpath("//*[@id='caseList']/tbody/tr"));

    System.out.println("NUMBER OF ROWS IN THIS TABLE = "+tr_collection.size());
    int row_num,col_num;
    row_num=1;
    for(WebElement trElement : tr_collection)
    {
        List<WebElement> td_collection=trElement.findElements(By.xpath("td"));
        System.out.println("NUMBER OF COLUMNS="+td_collection.size());
        col_num=1;
        for(WebElement tdElement : td_collection)
        {
            System.out.println("row # "+row_num+", col # "+col_num+ "text="+tdElement.getText());
            col_num++;
        }
        row_num++;
    }
```

You can write your verify step above or below of syso statement.

```
 System.out.println("row # "+row_num+", col # "+col_num+ "text="+tdElement.getText());

  if (tdElement.getText().contains("Draft")){
    // to do something
  }
```

Comment: @Sanchit Did you verified this?

Comment: Yes. Tried this. Now getting this error `stale element reference: element is not attached to the page document`

Comment: This exception will occurs when the webelement is destroyed from the DOM. Perform  debug at which line your are getting this exception. Is there any page refresh happening before using that web element? If happens we need to find the element again and perform operation on it.

Answer (score 0):

You are retrieving `getText()` from a `List<WebElement>` - that's why you are getting an error. Get `WemElement` from this list first and then get its text:

```
String caseStatus = null;
if (!newcase.isEmpty())
{
    caseStatus = newcase.get(0).getText();
}
...
```

Note: this code will get the first element from the collection. You may need to iterate through all elements using `for` loop:

```
for (WebElement item : newCase)
{
    String text = item.getText();
    ...
}
```

Comment: Understood but do I verify if text is present?

Comment: this still doesn't print whole data present in the row.

Comment: You are finding a `tr` elements. The text can be present in a table cells - `td` element. Find and iterate through cell and get their text. Look for @Akarsh answer for an example